# use req.body data from the api route handler in a external javascript file in nextjs api

Tags: node.js, express, next.js, backend

I need to send the **req.body** (data received from the client to API route via post request) data from the API route to a separate javascript file in the backend api.

```
const payload = {}
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  payload = req.body
  res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' })
}

export default handler
```

I declared a variable outside the route handler function and assigned **req.body** to it, but then I realized that I can't use this global variable inside the handler function.  I don't know the reason. Is there any specific way of achieving what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: What do you mean by "separate javascript file in the backend api". Is this another API endpoint?

Comment: a javascript file that has a global object Eg: payload = {data1: xyz,  data2: ghy }

Answer (score 0):

I request to please elaborate the use case a bit more. Based on current requirements.
I can understand that-
You need to send the req.body to another JavaScript file. Now here can be 2 cases.

1. You need to store req.body in a file, and use it for later processing.
2. Pass the req.body to another function which is present in another JavaScript file.
   In this case, you can export the function from another file and import in this main file and call the function in your controller and pass req.body as Payload.

I think your use case will be second one, if not please update question and I will be happy to help you out.

Comment: My case is first one. In simple words I wanted to make the req.body as a global object. For now I figured it out. I assigned req.body to global.payload and now it became global   |           global.payLoad = req.body |

Comment: Great. Ensure to delete the global payload variable after using, as it may led to security issues

Comment: I'm not using any database, I'm using these values to generate pdf. I'm assuming it must be getting removed by itself. Or, if there is any specific way to delete it, please let me know.

Comment: If you're not using a database - why don't you do this in the client so you can use static site generation?